# How does one find the maximum amount of force an object can withstand before it breaks, as into 2 or more pieces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

What inspired me to ask this question was from my curiosity and hobby to understand the Science/Physics behind comics, anime, and mangas. I've seen tables of the ultimate tensile strength or yield strength of various objects before they break but it's still not what I'm looking for. To be more specific, I'm not asking how much static load some object can withstand until it breaks but more of how much force, such as from punching or kicking, can some object withstand before it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are interested in impact forces and the the impact strength of materials. For a description of impulse of force see: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/impulse.html. A common standard test for determining impact strength is the ASTM Izod Impact Strength test. For information on that, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Izod_impact_strength_test

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!